# Cognos 10.2.1 to_date function

Tags: cognos-10

Report Studio Reports are recently migrated from Cognos 8.4.1 to Cognos 10.2.1.In cognos 10, to_date(timestamp) function is not working which was perfectly working in cognos 8.4.1. Any report which got following expression in the filter are failing in Cognos 10 but works fine in Cognos 8.

```
to_date(trunc([Presentation Layer].[Query Subject].[FROM_DATE])) >= ?fromDate?
```

FROM_DATE = date from data source(Oracle) which is of type timstamp
fromDate = is a report parameter passed in the query string

Can some one please advise the fix/work around on this issues. We are talking about several reports that got this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the CAST() function? Usage would be cast([Presentation Layer].[Query Subject].[FROM_DATE],date). CAST is a Cognos-specific function which will be translated into the DB provider-specific function within the SQL sent to to the DB.